# Emberjs: Jquery Function not being called after Handlebars Template is loaded

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have an EmberJS application where I'm trying to call a jquery function that positions some div elements on a page using `.css()` for a specific handlebars template.

My problem is that when EmberJS loads in the template to my application (whether by url change, or `{{linkTo}}`, the jquery functions don't get fired.  That said, if I refresh the page, they fire just fine and everything is great. Additionally, I have an event listener for if the page changes width, which will cause the function to refire, and this works fine too.

My guess is that Ember doesn't actually call the jquery function once the template is initially loaded. Anyway to get around this?  I was wondering if maybe I should try to use handlebars to directly call a function from my scripts.js?  Thanks for your help!

Additionally, Is this possible without leveraging Views? Maybe just with Handlebars and components?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: You need to run the jQuery code in one of your views. Learn in my blog how to do this http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put code like that in the `didInsertElement` method of your view. So for example if your template is `project/index`, you would do:

```
App.ProjectIndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: 'project/index',
    didInsertElement: function() {
    /// Your jQuery code here
    }
});
```

Comment: awesome :) gonna give it a go.

Comment: Why don't you want to use views?

Comment: well, according to this thread, views will eventually be done away with in exchange for handlebars and components. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/mvc-flow-chart-is-this-helpful/2287/12

Comment: Components are simply extensions of views. The view base class isn't going anywhere. The component/view layer is definitely the right place to interact with the dom as it's the only layer that receives dom and rendering events. I should add that you should always consider using a component instead of a straight view, since components completely encapsulate the context of your view and force you to define the interfaces by which your component interacts with the rest of your app.

Comment: I completely agree with Dan. Generally if you have the same 'view' that you use in different parts of your app, you should probably implement it as a `component`. Examples could be an inline edit form or a bar chart. Note that every template will have an associated view by default, which you can override (and add your own functionality, fo example by putting jQuery code in `didInsertElement`) just as described in the answer. If your jQuery code pertains only to that one template it is fine to put in the template view, otherwise refactor it into a component.