# How do I run custom javascript after ember handlebars template has loaded?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I am trying to load Javascript that I inherited from the Zurb Foundation framework (CSS/UI bootstrap), specifically to [handle "equalization" of cell heights in a grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html). Their library is mostly CSS, which fits ember perfectly, but some of it requires Javascript to do what it does.

In my app, I have the router, routes, models, controllers, and templates. So far I don't have a view or component yet (nor do the docs make it super clear that they're what I should be using).

Is there a way in my controller/route/template to detect that a specific template has finished loading, and run some custom Javascript?

The custom Javascript I need to run:

```
$(document).foundation()

// OR, for speed's sake a more limited reload:
$(document).foundation('equalizer', 'reflow');
```

Comment: As you can see, it loads as some sort of jQuery add on. However, If I need to do some sort of DI to get the jQuery object I can probably figure that out myself. It wouldn't hurt to include that in any answers, but isn't necessary :)

Comment: Also this seems related, but I'm still confused if this is what I use a view for or not, especially since Ember has changed so much over the last year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166641/emberjs-jquery-function-not-being-called-after-handlebars-template-is-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `didInsertElement` is sometimes not working properly especially if you have nested views for example `form inputs` or `view` rendered in an `{{#each}}`. I would suggest you to run things like this

```
 didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
  },
  afterRenderEvent : function(){
    this.$(document).foundation('equalizer', 'reflow');
  }
```

You can even make it more generic, follow the instructions [there](http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/) which i think are the best practice for this kind of recurrent problematic

Comment: I had to use `this.$(document).foundation('equalizer', 'reflow')` for it to work, but it is definitely calling my script. Thanks!

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham i eddied with your working this.$(document) the this.$() return the jQuery view context by default so if your library is document wise it's normal it was not working properly my apologize.

Comment: According to this PR, https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5631, it seems the nested view order thing got (partially?) resolved in Ember 1.8.0. Having just looked through the code, `didInsertElement` is called at the end of the insertElement call, which is *right* before the `afterRender` queue is started, and `didInsertElement` now gets called in child-to-parent order. Unless there's something in the `afterRender` queue that could conflict with my call if done afterwards, I think queueing is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, and I just realized the reason I had to call `this.$(document).` was because I was building my view as a cheat just to run that script, and the view isn't inserting the element I'm targeting. I'll probably get better perf if I use the view correctly ;) Cheers!

Comment: Well i run in to troubles with this bit more than four month ago :]  and as it was a hell of a bug to find out i kept using this when working with nested view.

Comment: ...and now I realized views can be block helpers, so my "cheat" isn't really a cheat, as long as I use it as a block view. Then I can properly target that element. Thanks one last time, everybody!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until ember as added the DOM to the page that you want to call the jQuery code on.

Use a component and in the didInsertElement hook call the function.

Something like this.

```
equalizer: function(){
  this.$().foundation('equalizer', 'reflow');
}.on('didInsertElement')
```